# I ran the command "rake test" and I get this error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to ruby on rails so I really don't understand this error.
I did install the gem MiniTest, but I'm lost as to how to continue.

```
 rake test
/Users/mesmer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/turn-0.8.3/lib/turn/autorun/minitest.rb:14:in `<top (required)>': MiniTest v1.6.0 is out of date. (RuntimeError)
`gem install minitest` and add `gem 'minitest' to you test helper.
    from /Users/mesmer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /Users/mesmer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
    from /Users/mesmer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/mesmer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /Users/mesmer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/turn-0.8.3/lib/turn.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/mesmer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /Users/mesmer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
    from /Users/mesmer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/mesmer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /Users/mesmer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/test_help.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/mesmer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /Users/mesmer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
    from /Users/mesmer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/mesmer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /Users/mesmer/Dropbox/Dev/Rails/depot/test/test_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/mesmer/Dropbox/Dev/Rails/depot/test/unit/helpers/products_helper_test.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/mesmer/Dropbox/Dev/Rails/depot/test/unit/helpers/products_helper_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/mesmer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:10:in `require'
    from /Users/mesmer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from /Users/mesmer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in `each'
    from /Users/mesmer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/mesmer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `select'
    from /Users/mesmer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Which version of `minitest` do you have installed? `gem list minitest` should show you.

Comment: Also do you have `minitest` included in your `Gemfile`? Can you post your `Gemfile` contents here?

Comment: Do you have `gem 'minitest'` in your Gemfile? Does calling `bundle exec rake test` make the error go away?

Comment: Did you use `bundle install`, before run `rake test`?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, unfortunately neither the Rails tutorial nor the book I'm using mentioned having to edit the Gemfile, but it appears to be necessary.

I had to add an extra line in `/Gemfile` to include 'minitest':

```
group :test do
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', :require => false
  gem 'minitest'                  ####### add this line #######
end
```

After that, `rake test` seemed to work OK.  Bizarre that the error referred to an outdated version though. Don't get that.

Comment: Just started to get this problem whiel learning rails. I'm assuming its something quite recent? Eithercase it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should do:

```
bundle update minitest
```

in your console (be sure not to point to any particular version in your Gemfile).

Answer (score 0):

In Rails you manage the gems used in your project with [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/), which you'll do by editing `Gemfile`, located in the root of your project. In this instance you'll want to add the line `gem 'minitest'` inside the `group :test do ...` section. Then save `Gemfile` and run `bundle install` from the command line.

The line about your "test helper" refers to the file `test/test_helper.rb`. So after installing the gem with Bundler as above you'll want to open `test/test_helper.rb` and add the line `require 'minitest'` somewhere near the top (probably right after any `require` lines that are already there).